# Javascript: Why aren't my global variables updating?

Tags: javascript, export, global-variables, hoisting

Here is what I am trying to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/88ow75kqx0
in the test.js file I am updating the variable then exporting it but it is not being updated properly and still has its original value when sent. Is this because of hoisting?

```
var send = 5;

function modify() {
  send = 8;
}
export var globalVariable = {
  //send does not change to 8
  output: send
};
```

and in testpass.js:

```
import { globalVariable } from "./test.js";
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  //prints 5 not 8
  alert(globalVariable.output);
});
```

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question itself. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your initial issue. Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question. Also provide a properly detailed explanation of what the code should do and what it is or isn't doing as well as any errors. See [ask]

Comment: I fixed it properly

Comment: Nothing shown ever calls `modify()`. Also updating a primitive variable won't update the object that references it's value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call modify function

```js
var send = 5;

function modify() {
  send = 8;
}

modify();

 export var globalVariable = {
  //send does not change to 8
  output: send
};

console.log(globalVariable)
```

made changes to update to code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/8ljqv41wr0